# "Zuschauer aus so entfernten Gegenden wie....."-role of "so"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence:

"Zuschauer aus **so entfernten Gegenden** wie Kent, Yorkshire und Dundee haben mich heute angerufen und berichtet, dass anstelle des Regens ganze Schauer von Sternschnuppen niedergegangen sind."

Does "so entfernten Gegenden wie" basically mean such "such distant/remote regions as"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "so" in this cases emphasizes how far away the regions mentioned are. So a fitting translation could be

> Viewers from regions as far away as Kent, Yorkshire and Dundee called and reported (...).

or

> Viewers even from regions like Kent, Yorkshire and Dundee called and reported (...).

To phrase it as "such far away regions as" could work as well, but I'm not sure it transports the emphasis as well.

As a side note, "entfernte Gegenden" in this case doesn't mean as much that the regions are remote (as in "out in the sticks"), but rather far away *from the speaker's location*. So "far away" or something similar might fit better than "distant" or "remote".

Comment: My best translation would be "from regions as far away as Kent, etc."